# How to use clang and distcc to compile on a slave of a different architecture (e.g. Mac/Linux)

Tags: c++, clang, distcc

I want to use distcc to compile code from my Mac to a bunch of Linux hosts, but I can't figure out how to make everything "line up". I've successfully used distcc from Mac to Mac, so I have a general idea of how to set things up.

I'm using Clang 4.0 and have it installed and working on both Mac and Linux. The following command compiles fine without the `distcc` at the beginning, but after adding distcc, I get the following issues:

```
distcc /Users/xaxxon/Downloads/clang+llvm-4.0.0-x86_64-apple-darwin/bin/clang++   -I/usr/local/include -I/Users/xaxxon/v8toolkit/./include -I/Users/xaxxon/v8/include  -stdlib=libc++ -g -Werror=return-type -g   -std=gnu++1z -o CMakeFiles/v8toolkit_static.dir/src/v8toolkit.cpp.o -c /Users/xaxxon/v8toolkit/src/v8toolkit.cpp
```

I'm not sure what compiler is being picked up on Linux, nor do I know how to find out. It's possible it's picking up GCC instead of Clang.

My first concern is this:

```
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-stdlib=libc++'
```

My first error is:

```
In file included from /Users/xaxxon/v8toolkit/src/v8toolkit.cpp:5:
In file included from /usr/include/assert.h:44:
In file included from /Users/xaxxon/Downloads/clang+llvm-4.0.0-x86_64-apple-darwin/bin/../include/c++/v1/stdlib.h:94:
/usr/include/stdlib.h:250:20: error: blocks support disabled - compile with -fblocks or pick a deployment target that supports them
int atexit_b(void (^)(void)) __attribute__((availability(macosx,introduced=10.6)));
```

The next error I get (which becomes the first error if I manually add `-fblocks` to the compilation command (which isn't needed on a native Mac build) is:

```
/Users/xaxxon/Downloads/clang+llvm-4.0.0-x86_64-apple-darwin/bin/../include/c++/v1/__tuple:289:13: error: unknown type name '__type_pack_element'
    typedef __type_pack_element<_Ip, _Types...> type;
            ^
/Users/xaxxon/Downloads/clang+llvm-4.0.0-x86_64-apple-darwin/bin/../include/c++/v1/__tuple:289:32: error: expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers
    typedef __type_pack_element<_Ip, _Types...> type;
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
/Users/xaxxon/Downloads/clang+llvm-4.0.0-x86_64-apple-darwin/bin/../include/c++/v1/__tuple:356:43: error: use of undeclared identifier '__type_pack_element'
      typename _ApplyFn::template __apply<__type_pack_element<_Idx, _Types...>>...
                                          ^
/Users/xaxxon/Downloads/clang+llvm-4.0.0-x86_64-apple-darwin/bin/../include/c++/v1/__tuple:357:6: error: expected a type
    >;
```

I don't understand if I'm doing something fundamentally wrong or if there's something small I'm missing which is making the Linux compiler act differently.

I just made sure to have Clang on Linux in the same named directory and now am only getting the `-fblocks` and `unused during compilation -stdlib=libc++` issues.

I can get everything to compile (albeit with warnings), but when it links, I get:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file CMakeFiles/v8toolkit_shared.dir/src/debugger.cpp.o, file was built for
unsupported file format ( 0x7F 0x45 0x4C 0x46 0x02 0x01 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00
0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 ) which is not the architecture being linked
(x86_64): CMakeFiles/v8toolkit_shared.dir/src/debugger.cpp.o
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the `-target` flag fixes everything! In my case, for [Mac OS X v10.11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_El_Capitan) (El Capitan), the target triple is:

```
-target x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
```

for a build command of:

```
distcc /Users/xaxxon/Downloads/clang+llvm-4.0.0-x86_64-apple-darwin/bin/clang++  -Dv8toolkit_shared_EXPORTS -I/usr/local/include -I/Users/xaxxon/v8toolkit/./include -isystem /Users/xaxxon/v8/include  -stdlib=libc++ -g -Werror=return-type -target x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 -g -fPIC   -std=gnu++1z -o CMakeFiles/v8toolkit_shared.dir/src/v8toolkit.cpp.o -c /Users/xaxxon/v8toolkit/src/v8toolkit.cpp
```

You can get the current host's target by typing `clang -v`:

```
$ clang -v
clang version 4.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_400/final)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 <<==== THIS LINE HERE
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Users/xaxxon/Downloads/clang+llvm-4.0.0-x86_64-apple-darwin/bin
```

The following CMake lines will grab (and print) the triple for the current machine:

```
# Get the target triple for the current host by calling clang -v and then stripping out the Target: value from its output.  CMake regex syntax is quite limited.
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} -v ERROR_VARIABLE CLANG_VERSION_INFO)
string(REGEX REPLACE ".*Target:[\r\n\t ]*([^\r\n\t]*).*Thread model.*" "\\1" TARGET_TRIPLE ${CLANG_VERSION_INFO})
message(STATUS "TARGET TRIPLE: '${TARGET_TRIPLE}' END")
```

Much thanks to @duskwuff and oftc.net #llvm for help figuring this out!

Answer (score 2):

As long as you specify the `-target` flag, you can even cross-compile, because Clang is a native cross compiler.

*[Cross-compilation using Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/CrossCompilation.html)*